# How does a skull mend after a surgery?

Tags: brain, post-surgical, skull, sutures

After a [craniotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craniotomy), a large piece of a man's skull may be removed.

That bone piece has to be put back, right?

How to fix it and the bone piece can join the skull normally as it used to be?

There may be different methods as the bone piece's size may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you cited answers your question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craniotomy

> The amount of skull that needs to be removed depends on the type of
>   surgery being performed. The bone flap is then replaced using titanium
>   plates and screws or another form of fixation (wire, suture, etc.).

Comment: So that bone plate needs to be replaced by man-made structure? Why can not we put it back? At least skins are on it and hairs may grow again.

Comment: @questionhang No, the skin and hair are retained and remain attached to the person. They aren't attached to the skull. Only the bone itself is removed, not the skin and tissue covering it. Replacing it with man-made material is easier, cheaper and safer for the patient.

Comment: Can we put the original bone back? Is it dead after removal?

Comment: @questionhang It can be put back and often is. Read the "Procedure" section of the link you cited.

Comment: @Gregory I think Wikipedia does not specify it explicitly. Besides, the bone flap is alive even it can be put back?

Comment: @questionhang Yes.

Comment: @Gregory  an awesome method: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3115275/